# How to resolve the problems when using the KinfuLS package in PCL?

Tags: c++, gpu, point-cloud-library

I am trying to PCL, especially its GPU implementation of matching cubes algorithm. I use PCL 1.9.1 under Ubuntu 18.04.

However, I encounter some problems as listed below when I try to use its GPU package called kinfuLS for generating mesh from a TSDF volume.

The codes having problems are:

```
void RestoreCloudFromTSDF(float* tsdf)
{
    // create the cloud first
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA > tsdfCloud ;
    float* pTSDF = tsdf;

    for (int x = 0; x < m_iBoxWidth; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < m_iBoxHight; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m_iBoxDepth; z++)
            {
                PointT point;
                point.x = *pTSDF;
                point.y = *(pTSDF+1);
                point.z = *(pTSDF+2);
                point.rgb = * (pTSDF+3);

                pTSDF += 4;
                tsdfCloud.push_back(point);
            }
        }
    }

    // running matching cubes
    pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA > mc(m_iBoxWidth, m_iBoxHight, m_iBoxDepth, m_fVoxelSize);
    pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::MeshPtr modelMesh=mc.getMeshFromTSDFCloud(tsdfCloud);

}
```

The errors with the last two lines:

```
 1. warning: instantiation of function 
'pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::StandaloneMarchingCubes' required here, but no definition is available
standalone_marching_cubes.h:86:7: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
cloudregister.cpp:205:68: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::StandaloneMarchingCubes' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit

2. warning: instantiation of function 'pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::getMeshFromTSDFCloud' required here, but no definition is available
standalone_marching_cubes.h:97:7: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
cloudregister.cpp:206:89: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::getMeshFromTSDFCloud' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit

3. error: undefined reference to `pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::StandaloneMarchingCubes(int, int, int, float)'

4. error: undefined reference to `pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::StandaloneMarchingCubes<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::getMeshFromTSDFCloud(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> const&)'
```

Comment: @Mayur Thank you very much for editing the texts! Is there anybody can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no experience with the library, but at a quick look it seems to me that you need to include `standalone_marching_cubes.hpp` along `standalone_marching_cubes.h`, unless there is another header that includes them both